# Python tkinter multiple updates at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a french student in prepa classes and I have a work to do for my exam next year. My project is to simulate and optimize a botlleneck on a highway. I'm using Tkinter for the GUI and I display the cars using create_rectangle on a canvas. The problem is, my main function, made a loop using the after_idle method, seems to be running multiple times during a loop. For instance, the color of the cars (depending on the type of car, my 'modele' variable(sorry about coding in french, but the code will soon get fairly complicated and I want anyone in my class or teachers to be able to read it)) changes in the middle of the execution even though it is never modified in my code. The only option I see is that the list is modified during the loop, and so the color of the car added by the 'creer_voiture' function is displayed on other cars as well. So it looks like the indexes change during the loop, and I replace the data of a car by the one of another. I would be happy if someone found the answer, and thaks to the ones who will be taking the time to read my code.

```
###Imports
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

import random as rd
import time
import copy
import numpy as np

from operator import itemgetter

###Largeur de l'ecran
try:
    import ctypes
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    LARGEUR_ECRAN = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
except ImportError:
    LARGEUR_ECRAN =1024

###Constantes et parametres
NOMBRE_VOIES = 5
LONGUEUR_VOIES = 1000#m
LARGEUR_VOIES = 3.5#m
ABSCISSE_DEPART = 50#inferieur au quart de la longueur de voies
VITESSE_MAX = 130/3.6
TEMPS_NOUVELLE_VOITURE = 3

longueur_voiture = (4, 3.5, 3)#m
largeur_voiture = (1.5,2,1.8)#m
acceleration_voiture = (2.8, 2.5, 3)# m/s²
couleur = ('red', 'green', 'blue')
###Definition des variables

voitures = []#liste de voitures
#le format est (x,y,v,modele),
# avec (x,y) les coordonees du coin en haut a gauche de la voiture


voitures_prec = []#liste de voitures utilisées pour avoir les données avant l'actualisation
voitures_aff = []#les ID des voitures affichées
temps_prec = time.time()#en secondes, servira pour le dt aparaissant dans les formules
temps_derniere_voiture = time.time()#temps depuis l'ajout de la derniere voiture


###Variables additionelles
PAUSE = False#pour mettre l'execution en pause
###
###Debut programme
###


###GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x600'.format(str(LARGEUR_ECRAN)))
root.resizable(0, 0)



###Fonctions auxiliaires
def creer_voiture(voie, vitesse, modele):
    """
    cree une voiture et en ajoute les caracteristiques dans les differents listes
    """
    #ajout dans les listes:
    voitures.append((ABSCISSE_DEPART,3.5*(voie-1) + 3.5 - largeur_voiture[modele]- 0.2, vitesse, modele))
    L = longueur_voiture[modele]*echelle_x
    l = largeur_voiture[modele]*echelle_x
    x = ABSCISSE_DEPART*echelle_x
    y = (3.5*(voie-1) + 3.5 - largeur_voiture[modele]- 200)*echelle_x
    voitures_aff.append(route.create_rectangle(x, y, x+L, y+l, fill = couleur[modele]))


def creer_route():
    """
    initialise l'affichage des voies
    """
    global LONGUEUR_VOIES, NOMBRE_VOIES
    l = LARGEUR_ECRAN
    NOMBRE_VOIES = int(def_nb_voies.get())
    LONGUEUR_VOIES = float(def_longueur_voies.get())
    route.delete('all')#reinitialise l'affichage
    for i in range(1, NOMBRE_VOIES*4):
        for j in range(int(LONGUEUR_VOIES)//(13*4) +1):
            if i%NOMBRE_VOIES == 0:
                route.create_line(0, i*400/(NOMBRE_VOIES*4), l,\
                                 i*400/(NOMBRE_VOIES*4), width = '3.0')
            #les lignes continues separant les differents troncons

            else:
                route.create_line(j*13*4*l/LONGUEUR_VOIES, i*400/(NOMBRE_VOIES*4),\
                            (j*13 + 3)*l*4/LONGUEUR_VOIES, i*400/(NOMBRE_VOIES*4))
            #les lignes discontinues separant les voies
    route.create_line(0, 400, l, 400, width = '3.0')


def lancer_sim():
    """
    demarre ou relance la simulation
    """
    route.delete('all')
    creer_route()
    global PAUSE, temps_prec, temps_derniere_voiture, echelle_x, echelle_y
    echelle_x = 4*LARGEUR_ECRAN/LONGUEUR_VOIES
    echelle_y = 400/(4*3.5*NOMBRE_VOIES)
    PAUSE = False
    temps_prec = time.time()
    temps_derniere_voiture = time.time()
    main()


def pause_sim():
    """
    met la simulation en pause
    """
    global PAUSE
    PAUSE = True



###Calcul de la position de la i-eme voiture:

def pos(i, dt):
    x, y, v, modele = voitures_prec[i]
    #detection de la voiture precedante
    return x+v*dt, y



###Boucle principale
def main():
    #variables globales
    global voitures, temps_prec, temps_derniere_voiture, voitures_prec

    #initialisation des variables
    voitures.sort(key = itemgetter(0))#les voitures sont dans l'ordre inverse!!!
    voitures_prec = voitures
    dt = time.time() - temps_prec
    temps_prec += dt
    a_retirer = []


    for i in range(len(voitures_prec)):
        #initialisation des variables
        x, y, v, modele = voitures[i]
        L = longueur_voiture[modele]
        l = largeur_voiture[modele]

        #teste si la voiture sort du troncon:
        if x > LONGUEUR_VOIES:
            #la marque comme indesirable
            a_retirer += [i]
        #sinon:
        else:   
            #calcule la position
            xs, ys = pos(i, dt)
            #met a jour la liste voitures
            if dt > 1e-3:#si le temps es trop faible, on considere la vitesse inchangee
                v = (xs-x)/dt
            voitures[i] = (xs, ys, v, modele)
            #deplace la voiture
            route.coords(voitures_aff[i], (xs%(LONGUEUR_VOIES//4))*echelle_x,\
                         (ys+(3.5*NOMBRE_VOIES*((4*xs)//LONGUEUR_VOIES)))*echelle_y, \
                         ((xs%(LONGUEUR_VOIES//4)+L))*echelle_x,\
                         (ys+(3.5*NOMBRE_VOIES*((4*xs)//LONGUEUR_VOIES))+l)*echelle_y)

    #retire ce qu'il faut
    for i in list(reversed(a_retirer)):
        del voitures[i]
        route.delete(voitures_aff[i])



    #rajoute une voiture au besoin
    if time.time()-temps_derniere_voiture > 2:
        creer_voiture(rd.randint(1, NOMBRE_VOIES), \
                      rd.randint(90,130)/3.6, rd.randint(0,2))
        temps_derniere_voiture = time.time()
    lbl.configure(text = str(voitures))
    if not PAUSE:
        root.after_idle(main)






###Configuration de la fenetre et execution


route = tk.Canvas(root, width = LARGEUR_ECRAN, height = 400, bg = 'white')
route.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 9, columnspan = 9)



tk.Label(root, text = 'set lanes number : ').grid(row = 9, column = 0)

tk.Label(root, text = 'set lanes length : ').grid(row = 10, column = 0)


def_nb_voies = tk.Entry(root)
def_nb_voies.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
def_nb_voies.insert(0, '5')
def_nb_voies.bind('<Return>', lancer_sim)

def_longueur_voies = tk.Entry(root)
def_longueur_voies.grid(row = 10, column = 1)
def_longueur_voies.insert(0, '1000')
def_longueur_voies.bind('<Return>', lancer_sim)


lancer = tk.Button(root, text = "Lancer ou reprendre la simulation",\
                       command = lancer_sim, bg = 'green')
lancer.grid(row = 10, column = 8)


lbl_frame = tk.Frame(root, width = LARGEUR_ECRAN, height = 100)
lbl_frame.grid(row = 13, column = 0, columnspan = 9, rowspan = 3)
lbl_frame.grid_propagate(False)
lbl = tk.Label(lbl_frame, bg = 'white')
lbl.grid()

pause_btn = tk.Button(root, command = pause_sim, text = 'Pause', bg = 'red')
pause_btn.grid(row = 11, column = 8)




creer_route

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to do the debugging for you, which is off topic here. You need to narrow the problem down to something more specific, and show considerably less code.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @Bryan, but I've tried debugging it for hours now, and I'm pretty desperate. I feel the entire code is necessary, but the main problem is, I think, in the 'main' function. The issue is I don't really understand why this function could be run many times in the same time.

Comment: You call it from itself with `after_idle`, so it's going to be called once every few milliseconds.

Comment: That, I understand, but it seems the function is still runnung at the end of the run another function is called, so first, is it possible? Doesn't the execution stops when it calls another function?

Comment: Does it stop when it calls another function? No, it stops when the last statement in the function returns. A simple way to see what is happening is to a) use `after(1000, main)` instead of `after_idle(main)` to slow it down, and b) add print statements as the first and last step in `main` so that you can see when it is called.

Comment: Thanks, I wil try it

Comment: @BryanOakley I simply put a global variable set to true at the beginning of the fonction and to false at the end, with a while loop containing 'pass' in the 'main' function. I didn't notice any changes

Comment: I don't understand why setting a global variable would change anything at all.

Comment: The loop exits only when the variable is reset to False, so the execution is paused the time the function runs

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Bottom line, programming is deterministic. There's a reason your code is behaving the way it is. You simply need to step through the code a line at a time to see why it is or isn't calling a function when you think it should or shouldn't. In the code you've posted, you very clearly are running `main` repeatedly, as fast as possible.

Comment: OK I will try to solve the problem with this, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I may have spotted the issue : at the beginning of my main function, I sort a list with the coordinates of the cars, but I don't sort the list with the ids of the rectangles on the canvas. The question I still have is how to do it ? I need every change I do on my first list to be made on the second, like

```
from operator import itemgetter
l1 = [(x1, y1, type1), (x2, y2, type2),...]
l2 = [road.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1 +length, y1 +width),...]
l1.sort(key = itemgetter(0))
l2.sort#??????
```

thanks to @BryanOakley for his answers

I don't really know, so please tell me if I need to create another thread